# How to answer "Do family members intend to accompany you?" in national visa application (Germany) if they are only going for a quick (schengen) trip?

Tags: schengen, germany, long-stay-visas, schengen-visas

Here's the situation:

I'm applying for an internship visa to Germany (more than 90 days), and because it would be summer and also my first time in a foreign country on my own, my mother and (younger) brother (still a university student) are planning a trip of their own so they can help me move in and also spend a few days visiting different parts of Germany, etc.

Their itinerary is completely separate from mine except for the first flight (from our country to Berlin). After that, they will be staying at hotels/touring while I will stay in my new apartment and work (right away). They will return to our country in about two weeks.

It's also worth noting that because the embassy separated schengen/short-stay visa applications from national ones, they will be applying separately (and scheduled to do so in a month or so).

My first instinct is to just state that my mother and brother will be accompanying me, should they get visas, but I also want to make it clear that they will only be staying for a short time (otherwise there's no reason for them to be there). They will be mentioning this in their application anyway.

How should I phrase it? Do they mean "accompanying me" as in throughout the entire stay/for the same purpose of the stay (since it is on the national visa application) or traveling with me, like they are?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: It means do they plan to travel with you and remain with you.  You can answer 'yes' and add a not explaining it

Comment: Will you be interviewed? You can clarify it then if they ask.

Comment: @greatone yes, I will be. So should I check "yes" and clarify during the interview?

Comment: @egyptianlamp that's what I would do.

Comment: You should clarify *in the application,* not just in the interview.  Include a note as advised by @GayotFow to explain precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your own question, you've already composed an excellent response, and @GayotFow and @phoog have shared their expert guidance in their comments.

The plan is that you, your mother and brother will book the same flight to Germany; you'll take up residence and work, they'll go home in several weeks.

In your visa application, respond 'yes,' you would be accompanied, that your mother and brother plan to travel with you to help you settle in. Add an explanatory note, that they are applying, separately, for the Schengen Short Stay visa, describe their planned itinerary. Discuss it during your interview.

Your family members should answer 'yes' to the same, or similar, questions in their visa applications, explain the circumstances, and discuss during their interview.

Whatever the term:  accompany, travel, go with; fully describe your intentions and plans.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing - checked yes, and included an explanation saying their itinerary is different, that they will return in 2 weeks, and that they have a booked appointment for their visas on [date].

I wasn't asked about it during the interview, though. And I got the call today that my application for the visa was accepted - so the next step would be for them to apply on their (yet to happen) appointment.

Comment: @egyptianlamp that's great; good luck in your new job; have a great time in Germany.